# TFS Merge after all project architecture changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am working on a C# Selenium automation project, so I changed our all project architecture and design patterns. There are some new .cs and .xml files, some are deleted. Now working copy is older than 'Main' branch for one month. I cannot merge easily two branch because most of methods moved to other classes. Do you have any suggestions to do that ?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: it's throwing error or giving you to chose between what version to take ?

Comment: What would you expect Visual Studio to do for you, it knows even less about the relationship between the old and the new file than you do.

Comment: I don't expect VS to do this, any tools or suggestions I need. There are many diff between my two project, I can't lose the codes those are written in this period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any other way to reduce the merge conflicts. You have to use the Resolve Conflicts window to [resolve conflicts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts) that are blocking you.

If you are not going to resolve too many conflicts and not mind  to lose the "working copy" branch and history, you could just delete the old branch. Create a new one from "main" branch, keep working on the new created branch and merge back to main or pull changes from main to the new created branch.

Comment: I'll continue in this way. Thank you for advice